# DataFrame entries got round off when converted to txt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file, dataframe, rounding

[This is what the dataframe looks like before exporting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqISp.png)

[After that it becomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fERbE.png)

Rounding down is not what I want here; I want the text in txt.file look like what it is shown in the console. So how can I fix this? Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try writing directly from your Pandas dataframe instead of going through Numpy?

Try `DF.to_csv(‘output.txt’, sep=‘\t’, float_format=‘%g’)`

For more details see [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: Ty for your answer. Now I know more than one way to do it. Also, I figured out if I used '%g' in my original code as well, it will work out just as intended.